# Call to undefined function imageopenpolygon()

Tags: php

I'm trying to draw a open polygon with `imageopenpolygon`, because the normal `imagepolygon` closes automatically with the first position it has begun.Both functions exist and both syntaxes for use are identical.

They are officially supported:

[imagepolygon](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagepolygon.php)

[imageopenpolygon](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imageopenpolygon.php)

But when I try to use `imageopenpolygon`, my PHP setup don't like it, throwing me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imageopenpolygon() in /var/www/path/otherpath/index.php:65 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/path/otherpath/index.php on line 65
```

The syntax is correct, since the other (older) one works. `imageopenpolygon` was introduced in PHP 7 and is supported until 7.2.0, stated on the site. I have:

```
PHP 7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I wrote `phpinfo()` in an empty PHP file and it returned that all paths are loaded with 7.1. Image attached below:
[image: Apache Setup]

Also, my GD is updated for PHP 7.1.

What can it be? I need that function and theoretically it should work, shouldn't?

Comment: imageopenpolygon `(PHP 7 >= 7.2.0)` You dont have 7.2 yet I assume

Comment: @RiggsFolly This means 7 until 7.2.0, or not?

Comment: @Fusseldieb `(PHP 7 >= 7.2.0)` any PHP version greater than or equal to `7.2.0`, so you would need to update your PHP instance to `7.2.x+` to use the `imageopenpolygon()` function.